# Find and replace character in multiple HTML tags

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop through multiple HTML elements, to replace a character in those elements.

I managed to do it with only one element

HTML

```
<h2>test</h2>
```

JS

```
var test = document.querySelector("h2");

var text = test.textContent;
var arr = [];

for(i=0;i<text.length;i++){
  arr.push(text[i]);
}

for(j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
  if(arr[j] === "t"){
    arr[j] = "z";
  }
}

var newText = arr.join('');

test.innerHTML = newText;
```

but how would I go about looping through multiple `h2`s? The idea is to replace the letter "t" with "z", then push the new word into the HTML.

HTML

```
<h2>test</h2>
<h2>teeth</h2>
<h2>trent</h2>
```

I tried `document.querySelectorAll`, but not sure how to appropriately use `textContent` in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('h2')].forEach(test => { your current code without var test })`

Comment: Make a loop over the results of `querySelectorAll` and put everything after `var test = document.querySelector("h2");` inside the loop.

Comment: BTW, you can just use `test.textContent = test.textContent.replace(/t/g, 'z');` and do away with your two loops and the join...

Comment: Or, `.split('t').join('z')`

Answer (score 1):

That is because `querySelector` only retrieves a single element (the first that matches the selector). Fortunately there is `querySelectorAll` method that allows to retrieve all matching elements.

In addition to that, you can simplify your code quite a bit: since your goal is to **replace** any occurence of the letter `t` with the letter `z` then you should do just that. An element's `textContent` will always be a string, therefore you can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to do your operation.

```
    document
        .querySelectorAll("h2")
        .forEach(elem => {
            /*
                You can assign the result to elem.innerHTML or
                elem.textContent depending on your needs
            */
            elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent.replace(/t/g, "z");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```js
const replaceInSelection = (target, replacement, selector) => {
  const t = new RegExp(target, 'g')
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(
    el => el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(t, replacement)
  ) 
}
```

```html
<h2>test</h2>
<h2>teeth</h2>
<h2>trent</h2>
<button onclick="replaceInSelection('t', 'z', 'h2')">t -> z</button>
<button onclick="replaceInSelection('z', 't', 'h2')">z -> t</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceElementsText(selector, substr, newSubstr){
 if(!selector || !substr || !newSubstr){
    return;
 }

 const elems = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
 elems.forEach(el => el.innerText = el.innerText.replace(new RegExp(substr, "g"),newSubstr))
}

replaceElementsText('h2', 't','z')
```

Comment: He wants to replace 't' to 'z' not 'h'

Answer (score 0):

```
var hs = document.querySelectorAll('h2');

hs.forEach(h => {
  h.textContent = h.textContent.replace(/t/g /*target*/, "z"/*new char*/);
});
```

good luck! D;